# phpmyadmin Index page loading but not displaying any info

Tags: php, ssl, https, phpmyadmin, abyss

My *phpmyadmin* was accessible prior to installing ssl on my *abyss* web server using `http://`.

Since I have set up my ssl config when I try to access phpmyadmin on `https://` the page loads but nothing is displayed.

I have installed ssl across my whole domain.

Do I need to edit the `config.inc` file to enable *phpmyadmin* on ssl and if so what changes need to be made?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide more information related to your question in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a corrupt file somehow.

Solution was to remove all old phpmyadmin files and reinstall with latest version from the phpmyadmin website.

All okay now.